# How to improve GRE Math Subject score in a week?

Tags: book-recommendation, advice

I have a problem now: I need to improve about 15 points in the raw score in a week.

I have to take GRE Math Subject next week.
I have been reviewing for a week and I can get about 30/66 questions correct, which means I can solve most of the Calculus and Linear Algebra ones. I want to get in 70 percentile, so it is a must for me to be able to solve ~15 more questions correctly.

I find the probability, abstract algebra and topology questions that come up in the tests are very difficult to me.

Can you suggest me any books or tips to help me with these problems? I will do everything possible!

I know I started to prepare too late, but it was not at all my intention. Things just didn't go well to me recently...

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: I assume you have review books and practice tests. Pick questions at the edge of what you think you can do (or should be able to do). Try those. When you get stuck, ask here, showing what you tried. Include in your question your background and your purpose so as to encourage answers appropriate to your level rather than invocations of more advanced material.

Answer (score 1):

Most questions on the math GRE that are topics are generally twisted versions of basic facts. You should look up some GRE exams and do practice tests. I also recommend the Princeton study guide for the GRE math.

To be frank, it is difficult to give advise about the topic questions since they are quite diverse. I recommend understanding counterexamples such as the topologist's sine curve and among other oddities (strong counterexamples such as the Weierstrass function are particularly helpful) to help intuition. Also, remember fundamental theorems such as the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, fundamental theorem of linear algebra, and etc. For probability, you just have to remember definitions.

Comment: You mean fundamental theorem of finite Abelian groups?

Comment: Fixed! Thanks..

Comment: Is it okay if I skip topology and spend the whole week on reviewing Cal, Linear Algebra and Abstract Algebra? I will do as many tests as possible, trying to solve all questions but still focusing more on the three fields. Is it enough to make it to the 30 percentile...

Comment: 30 will put you around 40 percentile, but due to the test change, it will most likely lower due to guessing. (You are allowed to guess without deduction now) You should expect the amount of abstract algebra to vary.